# How can I see my choices in previous chapters?

Tags: dreamfall-chapters

Dreamfall Chapters is split into 5 books.

However, in the 5 months between Books 1 and 2, I forgot which choices carried consequences from Book 1.

Is there any way to review these choices?

Comment: On a side note, I wanted to know this because a conversation with one character had "Events from your past will shape your future" flash on the screen, but I don't recall any event involving this person at all.